# To show, that f $\in End_k(V) $ is invertible iff f doesn't have eigenvalue $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

My attempt:

Suppose: 
$a)\ \lambda = 0$ and $a \neq 0$

Then we have $f(a) = 0$. But if for some $a \neq 0$ we have $f(a) = 0$, then it means, that function $f$ is not one-to-one. Hence, $f$ is not invertible.

$b)\ \lambda \neq 0$

Then $f(a) = \lambda a$. So for each input value of $a$ we have distinct output. It means that function is invertible.

I am not sure if my proof is correct. Can you check it,please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is not correct.
You need to show two things (or 'directions').

$(1)$: $f$ invertible $\implies$ $\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue of $f$

*Proof:* We prove the contra-positive: $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $f$ $\implies$ $f$ is not invertible.
Indeed, if $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $f$, then there is some nonzero $v\in V$ with $f(v)=0=f(0)$.
In this case, $f$ fails to be injective, and hence is not invertible.

---

$(2)$: $\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue of $f$ $\implies$ $f$ invertible

*Proof:* We once again prove the contrapositive: $f$ not invertible $\implies$ $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $f$. If $f$ is not invertible, then it is either not injective or not surjective.

$(2.1)$ Suppose $f$ is not injective. Then there are $v,w\in V$ with $v\neq w$ but $f(v)=f(w)$. It follows that $f(v-w)=0$, so $v-w\neq 0$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda =0$.

$(2.2)$ Suppose $f$ is not surjective...
Then, what?
When $V$ is finite-dimensional, then $f$ is surjective $\iff$ $f$ is injective, and we could apply the previous step to reach the same conclusion.

But what if $V$ is *not* finite dimensional?
Here we, see the proof breaks down.
Indeed, a classical example is the right shift operator $\tau_r$ in a space of sequences

$$(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)\stackrel{\tau_r}{\longmapsto}(0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$$

No $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ is an eigenvalue of $\tau_r$. This is an opportunity for you to read up on the difference between eigenvalues of an operator and elements of an operator's **spectrum**.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed and good explanation!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

By definition (the second equivalence is true in finite dimensional space)

$$\lambda\in\operatorname{Sp}(f)\iff f-\lambda\operatorname{id}\;\text{isn't injective}\iff f-\lambda\operatorname{id}\;\text{isn't invertible }$$
Now let $\lambda=0$.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written for (b) does not work. An operator can have several eigenvalues so saying $\lambda \ne 0$ does not mean anything. I assume you are trying to say that *every* eigenvalue is non-zero. But even then not all vectors are eigenvectors so the equation $f(a) = \lambda a$ isn't going to be true for all $a$.

Instead, note that if $f$ is *not* invertible then $f$ has a non-trivial kernel. So $f(a) = 0$ for some nonzero $a$. But then $f(a) = 0a$ so $0$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you!Now it's completely clear!